# Query DSL - How to group by/retrieve an element in a collection

Tags: java, collections, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

In my scenario I need to retrieve and group by a field which is in a collection.

Here are the classes

```
class EntityA {

     //some other properties

     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entityA")
     @org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOne(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
     EntityB entityB;

}

class EntityB {

    //some other properties

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "entityB", orphanRemoval = true)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize(size = 30)
    @Getter
    private final Set<EntityC> entityCs = new LinkedHashSet<>();

}

class EntityC {

    //some other properties

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "field1")
    @Setter
    private Integer field1;

}
```

What I want to do is to group by the field 'field1' which is in EntityC and retrieve the same field with some other fields from other entities

Here is the sample code which I'm trying to retrieve

```
     EntityASearchCriteria searchCriteria = new EntityASearchCriteria();


    QBean<EntityA> retrieveFields = Projections.bean(EntityA.class, 
                                        QEntityA.entityA.field2,
                                        QEntityA.entityA.entityB.entityCs.any().field1,
                                        QEntityA.entityA.field2.count().as("count"));

    QBean<EntityA> groupByFields = Projections.bean(EntityA.class,  
                                        QEntityA.entityA.entityB.entityCs.any().field1,
                                        QEntityA.entityA.field2);

    List<EntityA> returned = repo.findAll(retrieveFields,
            EntityARepoPredicate.getPredicate(searchCriteria),groupByFields, Boolean.TRUE, null);
```

The error stack trace is as follows

```
    antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: field1
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.groupByClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1179) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:759) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132.createQuery(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:129) [querydsl-jpa-3.6.9.jar:?]
        at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:96) [querydsl-jpa-3.6.9.jar:?]
        at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:248) [querydsl-jpa-3.6.9.jar:?]
        at my.mimos.jpa.repo.impl.BaseQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl.findAll(BaseQueryDslJpaRepositoryImpl.java:264) [mimos-jpa-utils-1.0.11-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) [spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.findAll(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```

I tried adding

```
    @QueryInit({"entityB.entityCs"})
```

To the getter of the entityB within the EntityA to allow the longer initialization paths as mentioned [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/reference/html/ch03s03.html#d0e1831).

I have already done this type of work for the standalone fields and works fine. 
But since the field which I try to retrieve/group by is in a collection and I'm using .any() not sure I can do this.

Spring Data JPA version is 1.9.2.RELEASE and 
Mysema Querydsl version is 3.7.1

Appreciate any comment on this.